Is it possible to make a newline both for scripting and for html display in PHP?
I want to make a newline in PHP when using echo. However, if I want it to work on the browser I need to use <br/> and if I'm running it as a script from the command line I need to use \n.
Is there some way to create a newline that will be interpreted correctly in both?
echo '\<br>' or nl2br("\n") - makes a newline only in the browser
echo "\n" or "\r\n" - makes a newline only when it is ran through the terminal

You can check for anything that will be absent when the script is called through the terminal and set a constant accordingly. For instance, assume that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is null when using the terminal, then you could do:
if (is_null($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    define("MY_EOL", "\n");
} else {
    define("MY_EOL", "<br>");
}

You can then use this constant like this:
echo "First line." . MY_EOL . "Second line.";

Alternatively you could check for the presence of HTTP headers and do the same.

Just use PHP_EOL or "\n" to make a newline, if you want to display newlines in HTML, use the css style white-space:


.preline {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
<div>
default div
abc
defg
hij
</div>

<div class="preline">
pre-line div
abc
defg
hij
</div>



